# retrieving data from firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am studying in France and I have trouble finding French tutorials to solve my problem. I am therefore obliged to ask my question, hoping to have a satisfactory solution.

My problem is that I have trouble reading my data on firebase and I have spent three days on it.

[I have a structure like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opKhH.jpg)

I had started to code something, I was able to recover the key but I could not recuperate these values "nom" "argent" etc .

```
private Firebase mRef ;
mRef = new Firebase("https://authent-50e6b.firebaseio.com/users");
mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { 
    @Override
   public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String cle = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        Toast.makeText(ListeActivity.this,"la cle est : "+cle ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Hello Charaf Ahmed, 
Can you please post your solution, I am stuck on retriving data from fireabse. 
please send me your code only retriveing part and rules you have set in databse
Thank in advance

Comment: public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String cle = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    String nom = dataSnapshot.child("nom").getValue(String.class);
    Toast.makeText(ListeActivity.this,"la cle est : "+cle+" nom est : "+nom ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to John's is to use `DataSnapshot.child()` to get to each property:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String cle = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    String nom = dataSnapshot.child("nom").getValue(String.class);
    Toast.makeText(ListeActivity.this,"la cle est : "+cle+" nom est : "+nom ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup @Frank   . Luckily there are generous people like you

Comment: John's solution is the more scalable one btw. Mine is just the faster, more hacky one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You would need something like following (assuming you have `User` pojo whose fields map to those in firebase db)

```
User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
String nom = user.getNom();
```

Comment: Merci @John for your solution .

Comment: Pas de problème :)