# passing data from firebase to another acitivity

Tags: android, firebase

i am having trouble on retrieving data from firebase. There is actually two layout where first layout is called activity_a.xml this is for entering data to firebase and this works just fine. Second layout is called lyt_fragment_a.xml is for retrieving data from firebase.

I am successfully uploading data to firebase using layout activity_a.xml with java file called UploadSchedule.java. But i cannot pass the data that i have uploaded which i want it to be displayed on lyt_fragment_a.xml

I want the button to have additional function where it can pass. Currently it can only upload the data to firebase which works.

lyt_fragment_a.xml.

I am really hope to get the coding works, and i really appreciate all your help. Thank you

fragmentA.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lyt_fragment_a, container, false);

    uploadsched=(FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fbUploadSched);
    uploadsched.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(fragmentA.this.getActivity(), UploadSchedule.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return v;

} }
```

UploadSchedule.java

```
public class UploadSchedule extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText subjectA, contentA;
FloatingActionButton fbSend, fbRefresh;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference ref;
FireBaseHelperA helperA;
String descSubject, descContent;
TextView tsubject, tcontent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    subjectA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SubjectA);
    contentA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ContentA);


    fbSend = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fbSend);
    fbRefresh = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fbRefresh);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("monday");

    fbSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String descSubject = subjectA.getText().toString();
            String descContent = contentA.getText().toString();
            String userId = ref.push().getKey();

            schedItemA monday =  new schedItemA();

            monday.setSubjTitle(descSubject);
            monday.setSubjContent(descContent);
            ref.child(userId).setValue(monday);

            subjectA.setText("");
            contentA.setText("");



        }
    });

    fbRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ref.child("monday").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    schedItemA monday = dataSnapshot.getValue(schedItemA.class);
                    tsubject.setText((CharSequence) monday);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    });

}}
```

lyt_fragment_a.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.testgram.testgram.Tab">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispSubjectA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject: "
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showSubjectA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dispSubjectA"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispContentA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What is in our class? "
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dispSubjectA"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showContentA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:lines="13"
    android:width="345dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dispContentA"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fbUploadSched"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />
```

activity_a.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.testgram.testgram.UploadSchedule">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fbSend"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.51"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fbRefresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispSubjectA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject: "
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SubjectA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dispSubjectA"
    android:hint="Enter your subject"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="85dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispContentA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What is in our class? "
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dispSubjectA"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ContentA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:lines="14"
    android:width="345dp"
    android:hint="Describe what will be going held in this day"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dispContentA"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="85dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ContentA"
    android:id="@+id/tsubject" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tsubject"
    android:id="@+id/tcontent" />
```

Comment: you want to pass `descSubject` and others to next activity or you want retrieve from firebase ?

Comment: Thank you for replying, I want to retrieve it and display it on another activity that is lyt_fragment_a.xml

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192113/retrieving-data-from-firebase-android

Comment: I have tried it but still failed to display it on another layout

Comment: we would like to see how you write the retrieve part

Comment: the retrieve part is at UploadSchedule.java starting on fbrefresh. By the time i run the apps and click the button, it crash

Comment: Show the errors.

Comment: the error point at onDataChange(UploadSchedule.java) on tsubject.setText((CharSequence) monday;

Comment: when i delete the char sequence, it says it cannot resolve method 'setText(com.......schedItemA)'

Answer (score 0):

All u need to do when the fragment is running u have to request for data .. which you not doing. Use onStart method so that whenever fragment is visible on your screen it requests for data.

```
public class MyBloodGroupRequestsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
''
''
''
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  ref = database.getReference("monday");

  ref.child("monday").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //U did this erliar u know what to do
                //schedItemA monday = dataSnapshot.getValue(schedItemA.class);
                //tsubject.setText((CharSequence) monday);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

}
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping, i have tried your code and it gives stacktrace on public void onStart where it says on start is never used and inside the bracket it needs expression

Comment: use onStart under onCreateView

Comment: it is still stays the same and give the same stacktrace error.

Comment: I am really sorry because i started to get confuse, where should i put the code? is it on uploadSchedule.java or fragment?

Comment: On Fragment.. U want to view your data on the fragment, right.

Comment: it crashes and shows error at when i try to click button that brings me to activity_a.xml com.testgram.testgram.fragmentA$2.onDataChange(fragmentA.java:61) it point at tsubject.setText((CharSequence) monday)

Comment: lets say the code that i wrote for retrieving does not work, can i have your example on writing retrieving code? it would be helpful

Comment: Yes it will work.. Use debug mode to see is your data arrived or not..and make sure your database path is valid..

Comment: Updated. It does not work and I tried so many approaches and example but still does not work. Again thank you for replying and help around.